# Put two DIVs side by side while keeping the image vertically centered

Tags: css

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#left {display:table-cell; width:448px; height:336px; vertical-align:middle; background:black;}
#left img {display:block; margin:0 auto;}
#right {width:97px; height:326px; padding:5px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; background:black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/image2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div id="right">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use `div {float:left;}`, the large image won't be vertically centered any more. What's the solution?

Comment: Can you give us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sure: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vmuwZ/1/)

Comment: Check out my answer or this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmuwZ/2/

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely sure what you wanted however I made a guess and stuck it in a JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf74D/). I simply set both containers to `float:left` and removed `display:table-cell`

Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't help as I want the large image centered -- both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

#### See if this is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vmuwZ/2/

#### CSS Changes:

```
#left {display:table-cell; width:448px; height:340px; vertical-align:middle; background:black; float: left;}
#left img {display:block; margin:20px auto;}
#right {width:100px; height:330px; padding:5px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; background:black; float: left;}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but adding a top and bottom margin to the image doesn't resolve the issue as the large image height isn't fixed. It's an image gallery where clicking any thumbnail displays a different image with a different size in the left division.

Comment: Can you fix the image height? Is it fine?

Comment: Not really. The images are of different sizes.

Comment: Hey, fix the image height using CSS na? So that your carousal too looks good, not odd when there is a smaller image and not big right?

Comment: "fix the image height using CSS" You mean setting a fixed width and height value for all the images? That'll damage the images quality.

Comment: Oh okay. But, each time when you scroll, when the new image comes, let it come, you can take the height of the left `div` and apply it to the right `div`, on each click on a thumbnail. What say?

Comment: "you can take the height of the left div and apply it to the right div, on each click on a thumbnail." That won't look good. The image gallery size shouldn't change.

Comment: Dude!!! If the image size changes, obviously the layout of the gallery changes right???

Comment: Not really. If you set a fixed size for the left division, which is the large image container, the whole image gallery layout will be fixed.

Comment: Yes, but what if the image size is bigger than the div's size? And how do you determine the largest image of all the containers and set the max size of the gallery?

Comment: "what if the image size is bigger than the div's size?" I adjust the container size to the largest image size in my gallery.

Comment: ah!!! :) in that case, do one thing... don't give the image as `display: block`... instead give image as `display: inline` or just dont give anything. and instead of `height` for the left `div`, give as `line-height`...